# Querys advanced multiple similar documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to make a query that a change is repeated in several documents. But I just want to leave me one of those documents. But I can not do 'FindOne', why should I bring more documents with those same characteristics. As such querys ago?

That means, I have this in the collection

```
{ x : ObjectId(1), y : [ ObjectId(2) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(2), y : [ ObjectId(3), ObjectId(1) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(3), y : [ ObjectId(4), ObjectId(2) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(4), y : [ ObjectId(3) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(1), y : [ ObjectId(2), ObjectId(4) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(1), y : [ ObjectId(2) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(4), y : [ ObjectId(3) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(4), y : [ ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(4), y : [ ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(1), y : [ ObjectId(2), ObjectId(1) ], z : "My string ..." }
{ x : ObjectId(1), y : [ ObjectId(2), ObjectId(3) ], z : "My string ..." }
```

Now I want to go so

```
{ x : ObjectId(1), y : [ ObjectId(2) ], z : "My string ..."  }
{ x : ObjectId(3), y : [ ObjectId(4), ObjectId(2) ], z : "My string ..."  }
{ x : ObjectId(4), y : [ ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2) ], z : "My string ..."  }
```

Data not know

- The Id 'x'
- String 'z'

Data if

- I have an Id corresponding to 'y' in this case corresponds to 2
- And I have a maximum number of documents or a limit is 100

If they realize the Id in 'x', is not repeated in the query, just choose one of the documents. Anyone know how that kind of querys?????

Comment: it's not clear to me, in your example why were these particular x:1, x:3 and x:4 records picked?  and why doesn't the result set have x:2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely certain I understand your question properly, but I think you are asking to select all documents with a y value of 2, and among those, to select only one document for each particular x value, and you don't care which document among the ones with a given x value it selects? Also, you wish to select a maximum of 100 such documents. Do I have that correct?

That query can be accomplished by using the following aggregation pipeline:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {y: 2}},
    {$group: {_id: '$x', x: {$first:'$x'}, y: {$first:'$y'}, z: {$first:'$z'}}},
    {$limit: 100}
])
```

A MongoDB aggregation pipeline consists of a sequence of steps that work much like a Unix pipeline, passing a stream of documents from one stage to the next. This pipeline has 3 steps:

- The first step, $match, receives as input all documents in the collection, and outputs to the next stage only those with a y value of 2. (Note that I used 2 instead of ObjectId(2) as you wrote in your example just make it correctly formed code that I could test.)
- The second step, $group, performs an aggregation. This means it outputs only a single document with a given _id field, which is specified in this case to be the x field from the input document. This will satisfy your requirement to select only a single document with a given value of x. In addition the x, y, and z fields in the output document are arbitrarily set to the values of the x, y, and z fields in the first document in the group, consistent with the assumption that you don't care which of the documents with a given x it selects.
- The final step, $limit, limits the number of documents returned to 100.

Please note that it will be completely unpredictable which of the documents with a given value of x is selected because the order in which the documents are processed is undefined, similar to the way that which document is returned is undefined when findOne matches multiple documents. It is generally advised to use a $sort step in the pipeline before using $first or $last if you want it to be predictable which document is selected.

I hope this helps, let me know if I've misunderstood your question or if you have further questions.